# Invariant subspaces under the set of all unitary linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $k$ and a set $S$ of endomorphisms of $V$ (=linear transformations from $V$ to $V$) we say that $V$ is $S$-simple if the only $S$-invariant subspaces of $V$ are $V$ and $\{0\}$.

We know that if $S=End(V)$ is the set of all endomorphisms of $V$, then $V$ is $S$-simple.

My question is if $U\subset End(V)$ is the set of all *unitary* ($B^*B=BB^*=I$) endomorphisms of $V$, is it true that $V$ is $U$-simple?

What we know about unitary endomorphisms $B\in U$ is that if $W$ is invariant under $B$ then so is $W^\perp$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are talking about linear transformations, it suffices to show what the elements of $U$ do on a *basis* of $V$.

In particular, pick an orthonormal basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. (I suppose we have an inner/Hermitian product, since we are talking about unitary transformations). Now:

> Any permutation of $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ extends linearly to a unitary transformation. (Can you see why?)

The crucial word here is "any". This means that if we have a $U$-invariant subspace $W\ne\{0\}$, we can take an orthonormal basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ of $W$, and complete it to an orthonormal basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$ of $V$.
Now permute, for example, $w_1$ and $v_{k+1}$. There will be then a $B\in U$ such that $Bw_1=v_{k+1}$, and so necessarily $v_{k+1}\in W$. We can do this with all the possible combinations, and we conclude that:

> $W=V$. (again, can you see why?)

Try yourself following these steps!

Comment: *Extends linearly* means that we can add more values to the image of the permutation?

Comment: It means this: a function $f(v_i)$ on the basis elements becomes a function on the whole space by linearity: if $v= a_1v_1+\dots + a_nv_n$, then $f(v)=a_1f(v_1)+\dots+a_nf(v_n)$.